# Where does this Pokémon video featuring Cleffa, Togepi, and Igglybuff come from?

Tags: episode-identification, pokemon

I've tried searching everywhere but I can't find the source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Pokémon element of the video is an advert for the Pokémon Trading Card Game Sun and Moon Cosmic Eclipse expansion.

The below video, of the full advert, is from the official Pokémon YouTube Channel.